# Error: No Module Named NLTK Python2.7 Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm on a Linux Red Hat server and I'm trying to launch a python script. I installed nltk, but when I start my script I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Here are my other python installations:

```
[~/Documents] >which python python2 python3
/bin/python
/bin/python2
```

However, nltk is installed on:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I don't want to change my path variable because I'm not the only one using this server, is there anything else I can do to overcome this problem? Where should I install nltk?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I added NLTK with sudo pip install nltk

```
[~/Documents] >which pip pip2 pip3
/bin/pip
/bin/pip2
pip3: Command not found.
```

My path:

```
[~/Documents] >echo $PATH         

/usr/local/java/java/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:
```

$PYTHONPATH does not exist, I can't install it using only pip

For the permission I think only root can read/write the nltk files:

```
ls -l 
drwxr-x---. 23 root root   4096 Nov 23 12:24 nltk
drwxr-x---.  2 root root   4096 Nov 23 12:24 nltk-3.2.1-py2.7.egg-info
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run your script using `bin/python2` directly? Or is `/bin/python` already pointing to that? Edit: Wait, when you say other Python installations, does that mean you have others which aren't in your PATH, are weren't shown by `which`?

Comment: @Steve Hi Steve, I tried with all my installations: /bin/python myfile.py, /bin/python2.7 myfile.py, etc. none of these commands worked..

Comment: try with  sudo pip install -U nltk

Comment: @eyllanesc Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: @Charles could you add more information to your question, such as how you added nltk originally (with pip?), your PATH, your PYTHONPATH if it exists, and the file permissions on the nltk package and site-packages directory? Edit: and try installing using both `sudo pip` and just `pip`.

Comment: @Steve Just added what you requested!

Comment: @Charles Thanks for posting, hopefully it'll help others find the problem. The last idea I have is to try running with `sudo python` since it looks to me like only root has read permissions.

Comment: @Steve Alright, I'll see with the system admin, because I don't have permission to run sudo python, but thanks I'll keep you posted if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the begin of you python script

```
import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Edit 1:

this must solve if above does not works:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Edit 2:

change the path in linux for only when script runs

```
from subprocess import call
call('export PYTHONPATH='/usr/lib/python2.7/':$PYTHONPATH,shell=True)
```

or you can call the module direct

```
<nltk.pth>
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

any python modules or packages in the directory will now be importable.

EDIT 3:

Well after some research maybe there is another way

first of all you need to append the directory to yout path with

```
import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

you will need importlib

```
from  importlib import import_module
```

Then you may import your module like this:

```
mod = import_module('nltk')
```

to get submodules you may do this:

```
module_you_want = getattr(mod,'module_you_want')
```

thats it!

Comment: did you place it before any other imports?

Comment: Right after the shebang line. Btw, I wrote #!/usr/bin/env python is this fine or should it be something else? I tried your 2nd answer it doesn't work either

Comment: Yeah I don't think that should work, that doesn't work with how Python imports libraries. Either way, I don't think that's the best solution, it's only a workaround and the main problem will likely cause more headaches down the road.

Comment: are you sure that nltk is installed? if your path is seted for another python version pip will install in another directory no in 2.7. The first code i wrote must work

Comment: Yes, it's in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: i had a similar problem here 3 days ago and the firs workaround worked as a charm to me! Good luck!